# Is there a way to capture OnSave() event in JavaScript based Office Add-in?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I want to capture Information like who created/edited the document (Excel, word or ppt), It's File path both Old and new filePath (if saved at a different place) and what is the change.

I want to capture these information whenever user saves a document (Excel or word). But I'm not finding any event handlers like OnSave() or OnClose() in Office Plugin documentation.

Can anyone please help me figure out a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that. You can find the list of available events on the [Work with Events using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events) page.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .